# How to randomly select key with specific value from hashmap in as little code as possible?

Tags: java, syntax, hashmap

### **This isnt a question about hashmaps. This is a question about shorthand java notation.**

I have a HashMap. This hashmap only every contains the keys 'n','e','s','w'. What i would like to do is randomly select a key from this hashmap but only if its corresponding value is true.

I have written a function to do this for me and it works exactly how i need it to. Now i would like to condense my code as much as absolutely possible, while still maintaining the same exact functionality.

**First thing i'll show you is how i create my hashmap for context:**

```
HashMap<String, Boolean> potentialMoves2 = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
        potentialMoves2.put("n", true);
        potentialMoves2.put("e", true);
        potentialMoves2.put("s", true);
        potentialMoves2.put("w", true);
```

**Next is the code in question:**

```
private void randomlyMoveCharacter(double x, double y, Character character){

            List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(Map.Entry<String,Boolean> mySet : character.potentialMoves2.entrySet()){
                if(mySet.getValue().equals(true)){
                    myArrayList.add(mySet.getKey());
                }
            }

            String direction = myArrayList.get(new Random().nextInt(myArrayList.size()));

            if(direction.equals("n")){
                character.mapY++;
                character.hasMoved = true;
            }
            if(direction.equals("e")){
                character.mapX++;
                character.hasMoved = true;
            }
            if(direction.equals("s")){
                character.mapY--;
                character.hasMoved = true;
            }
            if(direction.equals("w")){
                character.mapX--;
                character.hasMoved = true;
            }

   }
```

I'm pretty convinced that a good portion of this functionality can be written in shorthand in one line of code. I know at the very very least all of the if statements can be rewritten to be shorter. It would be ideal to, rather than have a strongly defined ArrayList object, to rather have a temporary Array[] which is never initialized. By this i mean performing computations on the code that calls the "toArray()" function.

**A Side Note**
I know for a fact that there is a better way to do what i want to do. Maybe using a Hash Map is a poor idea. Maybe using strings in general is dumb. I am fully aware that there is a more efficient way to do this. That being said, i am open to suggestions; however, i would still like to know how to write my code with less lines regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong data structure. You just need a `Set` of currently legal moves. I would also make the directions an `Enum` instead of a `String`, which makes the `Set` an `EnumSet`, and use a switch statement instead of the `if` chain.